# PHP работа над ошибками

Tags: php

Доброй ночи. Потихоньку убираю ошибки и предупреждения на страницах [регистрации](http://travianx5.ru/anmelden.php) и [входа на сайт](http://travianx5.ru/login.php), кстати ошибки одинаковые на этих страницах. Как мне лучше всего организовать проверку массива, который передается в `foreach()`? Нужно избавиться от кучи вот таких предупреждений - **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**. И что делать если условие попадает на `else`?

**UPD:** Еще бы убрать эти ужасные предупреждения на главной странице (3шт) и вообще будет отлично - **Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result**

Comment: вам разве вчера не сказали ?

`Warning: mysqli_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/GameEngine/Database/db_MYSQLi.php on line 2834`
значит что результат не получился, ошибка в запросе или соединении

Comment: Сказали, спасибо, но сейчас же вопрос в другом... Сейчас попробую пофиксить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (!is_array($data)
    throw new UnexpectedValueException('Data was supposed to come as array, '.gettype($data).' received instead');
// продолжаем код как ни в чем не бывало - в случае ошибки все, что идет после эксепшена и до соответствующего catch, выполнено не будет
```